# passing a variable from javascript to php

Tags: php, javascript, forms, variables

I'm trying to pass a variable from a js function to php form (in the same file).
Here is my form :

```
 <div id="hoursDetails" class="toogle_form" style="display:none">
      <table border=0>
            <?php
                 for ($i=0 ; $i<$N; $i++){ //$N is the variable I want to retrieve
                 echo '<tr>
            <td><div id="date'.$i.'" ></div></td>   
            <td>
             <input type=text name="action'.$i.'"  placeholder="Votre action"/>
             <input type="text" name="temps'.$i.'"  placeholder="nombre heures"/>
            </td>
                </tr> ';}
              ?>
      </table>
</div>
```

I tried to create a hidden input in the form :

```
<input type="hidden" id="variable" name="variable" value="" >
```

And to set the value from the js function using `$('#variable').val(10)` for example, but still don't know how to retrieve this variable when looping.
I can retrieve this variable from the controller, but is it possible to pass it from controller to the view without using index() function? (I'm using CodeIgniter
Could anyone help me please ? Thanks

Comment: Is the goal to be able to know which request you need to retrieve into your php ? If so you could name your inputs using arrays : `name="action[]"` Then you would just need to loop over `$_REQUEST["action"]` into your php to get all of the values.

Comment: The goal is to know the number of iterations I will do. And I get this information from my js function

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a variable from Js to PHP without making a request. Condiser that PHP is evaluated on server side, then when rendering on client side, Javascript triggers. If you need to pass a value from Js to PHP, you should try to use Ajax.

Comment: Actually I'm already using ajax to interact with the server side. But to which function should I send the Ajax POST request when php is in the same file ?

Comment: If using jQuery, use .load() as it lets you to choose a selector which will retrieve the data. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: ,thank you. But as my php and my js function are in the same file, I don't know to which url I should sent the request. And as it is written in my question , php is integrated into the form, it isn't a seperate function.

Comment: I can retrieve this variable from the controller, but is it possible to pass it form controller to the view without using index() function? (I'm using CodeIgniter)